# JSON not working with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there something wrong with my JSON?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ieyvl

```
var url = "http://x.com/json.js";

$.getJSON(url, function(response){
    alert("worked!");
    alert(response);
});
```

If its a "cross-domain" issue, then why does this work?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BHshC

```
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3E245DF445E37F50?v=2&alt=jsonc";

$.getJSON(url, function(response){
    alert("worked!");
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: use console.log(response);

Comment: What's the domain of the page executing that code? You may be running up against the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: No.. just checked it at jsonlint.com and it passed.. so it should be fine..  It's probably a cross domain issue

Comment: json.js - probably not the greatest name for json data

Comment: in second example: response headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://xml.hosting.subsplash.com/5KQ4CM/json.js. Origin
>   http://secure.codepen.io is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Read about the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You need to use JSONP if they support it. And if the server supports it look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

---

[EDIT]

I did not check, but if the Google example works, it is probably because Google Enabled CORS for that resource. That mean browsers that support it can request the resource with an Ajax call. Not all browsers support that type of *handshake* request.  [looking at you older IEs]

Answer (score 0):

It's valid JSON, maybe jquery has problems because it returns mimetype application/javascript instead of application/json

Comment: +1 THIS is true too.. It's trying to load it as `application/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

If you read jQuery.getJSON() document at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/,
it says following:
Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
Also to remember: as of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting server isn't handling the response type correctly, in addition you need to do this as JSONP or if using getJSON add ?callback=? to your url at the end.

```
var url = "http://xml.hosting.subsplash.com/5KQ4CM/json.js?callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, function(response){
    alert("worked!");
    alert(response);
});
```