# javascript callback function call itself until true

Tags: javascript, json, callback

I am running a function that i need to keep running until i get a response example

```
exports.getJson = function(url, callback) {

    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    loader.open("GET", url);
    loader.onload = function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback(response);
    };
    loader.onerror = function(e) {
        callback(false);
    };
    // Send the HTTP request
    loader.send();

}
```

ok the problem i am having is it will sometimes give me a response of null and i need it to run again.

so i am calling it like this.

```
    url = 'http://example.com/test.json';
    main.getJson(url, function(response) {
            if(response){
                addData(response);

            }else{      
//return no response i need to run the function again now until it comes back as true
            }       
    });
```

Can anyone give me a good way to do this maybe try at least 3 times then return false???

Thanks

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483580/json-not-working-with-jquery#14483661

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the code in  function and call it again:

```
var counter = 0;
function getData() {
    main.getJson('http://example.com/test.json', function(response) {
        if(response){
            addData(response);
        }
        else if (counter < 3) {
            counter++;
            getData();
        }   
    });
});
```